# Jackson - how to deserialize array of objects to an hashmap instead of ArrayList

Tags: json, jackson, deserialization

I have the following JSON string:

```
{
"version": 3,
"status": "ok",
"response": {
    "data": [{
        "id": "XXX",
        "namespace": "X",
        "url": "xxx.com"
    },
    {
        "id": "YYY",
        "namespace": "Y",
        "url": "yyy.com"
    },
    {
        "id": "ZZZ",
        "namespace": "Z",
        "url": "zzz.com"
    }]
}
}
```

And i have the following structure to deserialize it:

```
public class APIResponse {

    private String version;
    private String status;
    private Response response;
    //getters and setters
}

public class Data {

    private String id;
    private String namespace;
    private String url;
    //getters and setters
}

public class Response {

     private List<Data> data;
     //getters and setters
}
```

deserialization works great (i get the data array from the json deserialized to java list objects).

BUT: i wonder if i can get the data objects into an HashMap instead of a List such as the key would be the "namespace" from the Data class (thus i'll be able to get to the required "namespace" data object instead of searching the list).
Is that possible? i wasn't able to find anything like it.

Thanks

Comment: How using `Gson` to do custom deserialization from Json string to your desired type?

Comment: already using jackson, i suspect it should be possible

Comment: Yes, you can, but you have to write new custom deserializer for `Respinse` class.